# Contextual links don't display in a floated custom region

Tags: theming, views

I created two custom regions in my Drupal 7 theme and used CSS to float them side-by-side (to create columns). That worked fine, and I'm able to place blocks in the regions, but the contextual links don't display.

I tested them without the float, and the contextual links are right where they should be, leading me to believe that it's the float positioning that's causing the problem.

This isn't too big a deal, since I can go to Structure --> Blocks to administer them, but the contextual links are handy, and besides, it's bugging me and I want to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be related to positioning of contextual link region. In Firefox, Position:relative on contextual-link-region seems to be causing this. If Position:relative is disabled using Firebug links work once again, but contextual links do not.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add an "overflow:hidden;" to the wrapper of both the content and the contextual links to force it to fill the dimensions of its children. Either that or add a clear as a sibling of the elements. What's probably happening is the wrapper is being rendered to 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

Right click, shift click, double finger tap, or do whatever you need to bring up INSPECT ELEMENT in your browser and look around your page until you find the contextual links and then look at what CSS is no longer working with them with float.  They are most probably still there, just hidden from plain view.

Comment: I can see them in Firebug, and they're in the right place (within the HTML for the block), but they don't display. I tried changing the z-index of the contextual links wrapper, but that made no difference. None of the CSS is being overridden. "They are most probably still there, just hidden from plain view" is true, but I'm going to have to keep working on this.